# multiple textboxes effecting api

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am making a stress testing tool in C# and I am trying to have multiple textboxes to effect my API.

My current code is

```
HttpWebRequest.Create("http://API/flood.php?port=80&time=5&ip=" + this.metroTextBox1.Text);
```

I am looking for something like this

```
HttpWebRequest.Create("http://API/flood.php?port="+ this.metroTextBox1.Text"&time="+ this.metroTextBox2.Text"&ip=" + this.metroTextBox3.Text);
```

So it can can allow me to have 3 different inputs of my textbox to let me change the IP address, port and time I want the attack.

Comment: So where is the problem?

Comment: i get errors when i try to add textbox's to different sections of the code

Comment: Isn't that because you are missing the '+' signs after your textboxes in your second snippet?

Comment: 1. Post the exact error message(s) 2. You have invalid syntax, you need + between each `Text` and the following string (or use a different method of building the string)

Comment: thank you guys i added + to the end of each Text and it now works. thanks